Oracle 19c how to write a stored procedure with JSON output, I'm having trouble formatting the query to return a specific JSON object
The issue when I don't use AGG type I get a 'ora-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows using a json_object put into clob so using JSON_ARRAYAGG works I just haven't been able to figure out how to format the query properly to return the JSON object that I need.
I'm not a Oracle guru, or database admin, so that's probably the issue, any help from you guys would be great.  In the meantime I will continue to play with it and maybe I can find my own solution.
This is my Stored Procedure Package Body:
  PROCEDURE getCities
    (
    v_province_fips IN geo_counties.FIPS_CODE%TYPE,
    v_city_like in geo_cities.NAME%TYPE, 
    p_out OUT CLOB
    )
AS

    v_country_code geo_cities.country_code%TYPE;
    v_fips_code geo_counties.FIPS_CODE%TYPE;

BEGIN

    v_country_code := SUBSTR('' || v_province_fips || '',1,2);
    
            
        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECTAGG('CITY_SEARCH' VALUE
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'GEONAME_ID_CITY' VALUE c.GEONAME_ID,
                'NAME' VALUE c.NAME,
                'ASCII_NAME' VALUE c.ASCII_NAME,
                'LATITUDE' VALUE c.LATITUDE,
                'LONGITUDE' VALUE c.LONGITUDE,
                'STATE_PROV_NAME' VALUE a.NAME,
                'GEONAME_ID_COUNTY' VALUE b.GEONAME_ID,
                'COUNTY_NAME' VALUE b.NAME,
                'COUNTY_ASCII_NAME' VALUE b.ASCII_NAME,
                'STATE_PROV' VALUE p.NAME,
                'COUNTRY_CODE' VALUE c.COUNTRY_CODE,
                'COUNTY_LATITUDE' VALUE b.LATITUDE,
                'COUNTY_LONGITUDE' VALUE b.LONGITUDE,
                'FIPS_CODE' VALUE b.FIPS_CODE 
                )
                )
                RETURNING CLOB)

                
                INTO p_out
                FROM geo_cities  c
                JOIN  geo_counties b
                ON (b.COUNTRY_CODE = c.COUNTRY_CODE)
                JOIN GEO_ADMIN1_CODES_ASCII a
                ON (a.FIPS_CODE = v_country_code || '.' || SUBSTR('' || b.FIPS_CODE || '',4,2))
                JOIN GEO_PROVINCES p
                ON (p.FIPS_CODE = v_country_code || '.' || SUBSTR('' || b.FIPS_CODE || '',4,2))
                where  LOWER( c.NAME ) like LOWER( '%' || v_city_like  || '%' )
                AND c.COUNTRY_CODE = v_country_code
                AND c.ADMIN_1 =  SUBSTR('' || b.FIPS_CODE || '',4,2)
                AND c.ADMIN_2 = SUBSTR('' || b.FIPS_CODE || '',7)
                AND c.feature_code in ('ADM1','ADM2','PPL','PPLA', 'PPLA2')
                GROUP BY 
                c.GEONAME_ID,
                c.NAME,
                c.ASCII_NAME,
                c.LATITUDE,
                c.LONGITUDE,
                c.COUNTRY_CODE,
                c.ADMIN_1,
                b.ADMIN_2,
                b.GEONAME_ID,
                b.NAME,
                a.NAME,
                b.ASCII_NAME,
                c.COUNTRY_CODE,
                b.LATITUDE,
                b.LONGITUDE,
                b.POPULATION,
                b.TIME_ZONE,
                b.FIPS_CODE
                ORDER BY c."NAME", b.NAME,c.ADMIN_1;
END getCities;

This returns the following json object:
[
    {
        "CITY_SEARCH": {
            "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164138,
            "NAME": "Miami",
            "ASCII_NAME": "Miami",
            "LATITUDE": 25.77427,
            "LONGITUDE": -80.19366,
            "STATE_PROV_NAME": "Florida",
            "GEONAME_ID_COUNTY": 4164238,
            "COUNTY_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "COUNTY_ASCII_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "STATE_PROV": "Florida",
            "COUNTRY_CODE": "US",
            "COUNTY_LATITUDE": 25.60897,
            "COUNTY_LONGITUDE": -80.49867,
            "FIPS_CODE": "US.FL.086"
        }
    },
    {
        "CITY_SEARCH": {
            "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164143,
            "NAME": "Miami Beach",
            "ASCII_NAME": "Miami Beach",
            "LATITUDE": 25.79065,
            "LONGITUDE": -80.13005,
            "STATE_PROV_NAME": "Florida",
            "GEONAME_ID_COUNTY": 4164238,
            "COUNTY_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "COUNTY_ASCII_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "STATE_PROV": "Florida",
            "COUNTRY_CODE": "US",
            "COUNTY_LATITUDE": 25.60897,
            "COUNTY_LONGITUDE": -80.49867,
            "FIPS_CODE": "US.FL.086"
        }
    }
]

The query works as expected, it's the JSON format that is the issue.  I want to return a JSON object as follows:
{
    "CITY_SEARCH": [
        {
            "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164143,
            "NAME": "Miami Beach",
            "ASCII_NAME": "Miami Beach",
            "LATITUDE": 25.79065,
            "LONGITUDE": -80.13005,
            "STATE_PROV_NAME": "Florida",
            "GEONAME_ID_COUNTY": 4164238,
            "COUNTY_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "COUNTY_ASCII_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "STATE_PROV": "Florida",
            "COUNTRY_CODE": "US",
            "COUNTY_LATITUDE": 25.60897,
            "COUNTY_LONGITUDE": -80.49867,
            "FIPS_CODE": "US.FL.086"
        },
        {
            "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164138,
            "NAME": "Miami",
            "ASCII_NAME": "Miami",
            "LATITUDE": 25.77427,
            "LONGITUDE": -80.19366,
            "STATE_PROV_NAME": "Florida",
            "GEONAME_ID_COUNTY": 4164238,
            "COUNTY_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "COUNTY_ASCII_NAME": "Miami-Dade County",
            "STATE_PROV": "Florida",
            "COUNTRY_CODE": "US",
            "COUNTY_LATITUDE": 25.60897,
            "COUNTY_LONGITUDE": -80.49867,
            "FIPS_CODE": "US.FL.086"
        }
    ]
}


You want to get rid of the JSON_OBJECTAGG and the GROUP BY clause:
PROCEDURE getCities (
  v_province_fips IN  geo_counties.FIPS_CODE%TYPE,
  v_city_like     IN  geo_cities.NAME%TYPE, 
  p_out           OUT CLOB
)
AS
  v_country_code geo_cities.country_code%TYPE := SUBSTR(v_province_fips,1,2);
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'CITY_SEARCH' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
             JSON_OBJECT(
               KEY 'GEONAME_ID_CITY'   VALUE c.GEONAME_ID,
               KEY 'NAME'              VALUE c.NAME,
               KEY 'ASCII_NAME'        VALUE c.ASCII_NAME,
               KEY 'LATITUDE'          VALUE c.LATITUDE,
               KEY 'LONGITUDE'         VALUE c.LONGITUDE,
               KEY 'STATE_PROV_NAME'   VALUE a.NAME,
               KEY 'GEONAME_ID_COUNTY' VALUE b.GEONAME_ID,
               KEY 'COUNTY_NAME'       VALUE b.NAME,
               KEY 'COUNTY_ASCII_NAME' VALUE b.ASCII_NAME,
               KEY 'STATE_PROV'        VALUE p.NAME,
               KEY 'COUNTRY_CODE'      VALUE c.COUNTRY_CODE,
               KEY 'COUNTY_LATITUDE'   VALUE b.LATITUDE,
               KEY 'COUNTY_LONGITUDE'  VALUE b.LONGITUDE,
               KEY 'FIPS_CODE'         VALUE b.FIPS_CODE 
             )
             RETURNING CLOB
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         )
  INTO   p_out
  FROM   geo_cities  c
         JOIN  geo_counties b
         ON (b.COUNTRY_CODE = c.COUNTRY_CODE)
         JOIN GEO_ADMIN1_CODES_ASCII a
         ON (a.FIPS_CODE = v_country_code || '.' || SUBSTR(b.FIPS_CODE,4,2))
                JOIN GEO_PROVINCES p
                ON (p.FIPS_CODE = v_country_code || '.' || SUBSTR(b.FIPS_CODE,4,2))
  where  LOWER( c.NAME ) like LOWER( '%' || v_city_like  || '%' )
  AND    c.COUNTRY_CODE = v_country_code
  AND    c.ADMIN_1 =  SUBSTR(b.FIPS_CODE,4,2)
  AND    c.ADMIN_2 = SUBSTR(b.FIPS_CODE,7)
  AND    c.feature_code in ('ADM1','ADM2','PPL','PPLA', 'PPLA2');
END getCities;

Also, '' || 'something' is pointless as '' is identical to NULL and NULL || 'something' is simply 'something'.

This answer worked for me, thanks for the pointers and going through it.   good pointers and again thanks.

You don't need the objectagg, or the grouping.
With a simplified demo your query is doing this:
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECTAGG('CITY_SEARCH' VALUE
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'GEONAME_ID_CITY' VALUE c.GEONAME_ID,
                'NAME' VALUE c.NAME
            )
        )
    )
FROM c
GROUP BY c.GEONAME_ID, c.NAME




JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECTAGG('CITY_SEARCH'VALUEJSON_OBJECT('GEONAME_ID_CITY'VALUEC.GEONAME_ID,'NAME'VALUEC.NAME)))




[{"CITY_SEARCH":{"GEONAME_ID_CITY":4164138,"NAME":"Miami"}},{"CITY_SEARCH":{"GEONAME_ID_CITY":4164143,"NAME":"Miami Beach"}}]



or
[
  {
    "CITY_SEARCH": {
      "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164138,
      "NAME": "Miami"
    }
  },
  {
    "CITY_SEARCH": {
      "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164143,
      "NAME": "Miami Beach"
    }
  }
]

... which is a cut-down version of what you are seeing.
If you instead have a single object with a value that is an json_arrayagg of objects, then you don't need (or want) the group-by, and you get:
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('CITY_SEARCH' VALUE
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'GEONAME_ID_CITY' VALUE c.GEONAME_ID,
                'NAME' VALUE c.NAME
            )
        )
    )
FROM c




JSON_OBJECT('CITY_SEARCH'VALUEJSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('GEONAME_ID_CITY'VALUEC.GEONAME_ID,'NAME'VALUEC.NAME)))




{"CITY_SEARCH":[{"GEONAME_ID_CITY":4164138,"NAME":"Miami"},{"GEONAME_ID_CITY":4164143,"NAME":"Miami Beach"}]}



or
{
  "CITY_SEARCH": [
    {
      "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164138,
      "NAME": "Miami"
    },
    {
      "GEONAME_ID_CITY": 4164143,
      "NAME": "Miami Beach"
    }
  ]
}

... which is a cut-down version of what you want to see.
fiddle
